# Slide page up to make room for iOS keyboard

Tags: reactjs

**In React (not React Native), how can I slide the page-content up to make room for the iOS keyboard when a textarea element gains focus?**

Below please find my attempt. This now works fine. However, I am curious if this is considered good practice, or if there is an existing solution?

```
    // When the textarea element gains focus,
    // scroll the content up (to make room for the iOS keyboard)
    scrollContent = () => {
        console.log("Gained focus");
        this.scrollViewRef.current.style.marginTop = '-250px';
    }

    // When the textarea element loses focus,
    // scroll the content back down (since the iOS keyboard is gone now)
    unScrollContent = () => {
        console.log("Lost focus");
        this.scrollViewRef.current.style.marginTop = '0px';
        // The textarea's onBlur is causing the button's onClick not to fire
        // so need to manually call the button's onClick
        if(e.relatedTarget === this.buttonRef.current) {
            this.buttonRef.current.click();
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div 
                ref={this.scrollViewRef}
            >
                <textarea
                    onFocus={this.scrollContent}
                    onBlur={this.unScrollContent}
                />   

                <div
                    ref={this.buttonRef}
                    onClick={this.handleSubmitForm}
                    tabIndex="1"
                >
                    Save
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

In particular, if the user tries to click on the form's submit button while the textarea element has the focus, it will only trigger the textarea's `onBlur` (and scroll the page-content up again), but it won't call the submit button's `onClick`. Hence the need to check what element was clicked on in the if statement, and if it was the button, manually trigger the click.

Is there a better way?